# VB.NET: How to generate your own Shape

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas, geometry, shapes

I am working on a WPF application with VB.NET 2013. There are several Shapes like:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse
```

I read that it's possible to do your own shape. So I tried to build my own Class class Triangle:

```
Public Class Triangle
Inherits Shape

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property DefiningGeometry As Geometry
    Get

    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

But to be honest I have no idea what to do know. The samples I found look totaly diffrent to the ovveridesclass that appeared.

Any help please?

Comment: did this not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374643/wpf-custom-shape

Comment: Hi John, I tried to adopt the c# code to my VB.NET Project but sadly I failed