# Error extending Shape class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

Im getting an error in my C# code and I cant figure out why

```
namespace Memory
{
    class Meme : Shape
    {
        public int used { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The error im getting is:

> System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'

code creating the instance:

```
options.Add(new Meme()
    {
     name  =  option,
            used = 0,
            Width = 50,
            Height = 50,
            Fill = Brushes.Red
        });
```

Comment: Did you see the `throw new NotImplementedException()` line in your code?

Comment: Your DefiningGeometry is throwing that exception. Read the code closely.

Comment: So im very new to C# but it autocompleted my class by adding that line,

Comment: Yup, Shape will be internally accessing the overridden property and throwing that exception.

Comment: @WouterComello it expects you to implement it

Comment: This might help - it specifies a `Geometry` for a triangle shape: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374643/wpf-custom-shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom `Shape` class is supposed to actually return a `Geometry` of some kind. This will at least compile:

```
class Meme : Shape
{
    public int used { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(50, 50), 45, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

But if you don't know what geometry to return from the `DefiningGeometry` property, you might ask yourself whether you really want to create a custom `Shape` class in the first place...

Answer (score -1):

Looking at just the piece of code that you shown:

1) When you are 'extending' a class, given that the DefiningGeometry was an abstract property, you would need to explicitly provide an implementation for it. C# would automatically implement it using 'NotImplementedException' so that at least it could compile.

2) I've tried the code that creates the instance, and based on the above, it shouldn't call the 'DefiningGeometry' property. As such, it shouldn't actually throw the 'NotImplementedException'. There may be something else in your code that might trigger that exception.

--> Try mm8 suggestion of giving an actual implementation to verify if your code does call the DefiningGeometry method or not. Without changing this, your code should compile -- but if now it doesn't resulted in an exception, your other code may call this property.

--> I was guessing that in this code, the `name = option`, option here is a variable declared somewhere else (and that it doesn't have a 'get' implementation that calls a different method) -- as that probably another possible explanation.